# Permutating the coeffecients of equations with roots of unity.

Tags: permutations, roots, roots-of-unity

I"ve noticed the roots of
$$(x^k-1 =0) = (1-x^k=0)$$
This is simple enough  since changing +/- signs gives you the additive inverse which is equal at zero.
However this property can be also be thought of as the two permutations of the coefficents with the 2nd roots of unity e.g.

$ [(1)a+(-1)b=0] = [(-1)a +(1)b=0]$

Was wondering if this property holds for other roots of unity and under what conditions i.e.

Let $\omega =$ 3rd root of unity.  $$(\omega^1)a+(\omega^2)b+(\omega^3)c = 0$$

Do the six (3!) permutations of this equation have the same roots? Perhaps only if there are three distinct roots? What about composite roots of unity?

Any hints or further reading suggestions welcome. Thank you.

---

**Edit:**
To be more clear. If we take a random 3rd degree trinomial such as:
$3x^3+5x+14$ and multiply each coeffecient by one of the three 3rd roots of unity ($\omega^3 =1$  of course) and set the equation equal to zero we get:
$$\omega^1 3x^3+\omega^2 5x+14=0$$
This can be permutated in 6 ways by changing which of the three roots each coeffecient gets paired with:
$$
1.\omega^1 3x^3+\omega^2 5x+14 =0$$
$$2.\omega^1 5x+\omega^2 3x^3+14 =0$$
$$3.\omega^1 14+\omega^2 5x+3x^3 =0$$
$$4.\omega^1 14+\omega^2 3x^3+5x =0$$
$$5.\omega^1 3x^3+\omega^2 14+5x =0$$
$$6.\omega^1 5x+\omega^2 14+3x^3 =0$$

Per wolfram the roots of these equations are indeed identical.

The deeper idea here is that just as an additive inverse will be exactly the same at =0 as it is just a reflection. The same can hold for all nth roots of unity which can be seen as reflectional/rotational inverses of the nth degree and will be therefore be exactly equivalent at 0.

---

**Edit:** #2

After some more analysis and feedback from comments I think we can confirm this hypothesis is likely true only when:

1.n is prime.

2.The equation is of degree n.

**Edit:** #3
Upon closer inspection the six equations don't have identical roots. Instead there are two sets of complex roots that differ in which of their parts are positive/negative. Each set is only valid for 3 equations. So while perhaps still interesting, the hypothesis is false.

Comment: Interesting question! My first thuoght is that for $n>4$, permuting the roots of unity isn't necessarily equivalent to a rotation/reflection the same way it is for $n=2,3$ in the cases you have here. It might still hold, but at least not for that same simple intuition.
Edit: A few quick examples for $n=4$ shows it doesn't hold. Damn.

Comment: @tom Good point.  Perhaps it doesnt hold for any composite numbers.

Comment: You've chosen a permutation that is also a rotation, so you really just multiplied by $i$. Consdier the roots of $x^3+ix^2-x-i$ and $ix^3+x^2-x-i$.

Comment: Sure, then multiply it all by $x$ and you'll have a new root at 0, and the original three change still.

Comment: @tom You got a point there.

Comment: @Tom See edit #3

Comment: You have six equations. If you multiply (1) by $\omega$, you get (4). If you multiply that by $\omega$, you get (6). So those three equations are equivalent, and so they have the same roots. Similarly for (2), (3), and (5).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. I Didn't realize that at first. Adding the nth roots of unity to equation is just the same roots of the equation multiplied by nth roots of unity, giving $(n-1)!$ different sets of possible roots. So $n =3$ gives us two$(3-1)!$ sets.

Answer (score 1):

Two equations of the same degree can have same set of roots (with same multiplicity) iff one is obtained from the other by uniformly multiplying the coefficients  by   the same number.

For higher degree ($>2$) your modification ("permutation of coefficients" in your words)  will amount to each coefficient getting multiplied by different elements and hence will not have the same roots.

Comment: See Edit for clarification.

Comment: Yes, I saw your clarification. But the roots of the 6 equations you have typed in the edited version   are not the same. Make them all monic cubic equation  by dividing by coefficient of $x^3$. After this all the 6 monic equations have to be IDENTICAL for the roots to be the same. That's not the case

Comment: You make a good point. If we divide by the coeffecient of $ x^3 $ we end up with either equation 3 or 6 which for some reason give identical roots.

Comment: Both of your points are well taken. $(1-x)$ is simply $(x+1)$ multiplied by$(-1)$ so it isn't a good way to bring out my idea. Additionally by converting to monic polynomials it becomes clear that what i am suggesting is simply that having roots of unity coeffecients on the other terms gives equivalent results. With this in mind it is easier to see why this doesn't extend to composite nth roots of unity.

Comment: I think you were right after all. The six equations don't actually give 6 identical roots, rather two sets of 3 identical complex roots  with different +- signs. While i did try to verify +- signs the other day, I had not yet realized we are dealing with two sets of 3 equations and checked two from the same set carefully then eyeballed the rest. :(